# Laravel Access denied for database user

Tags: laravel

I've created a MySQL user, granted privileges, and a database:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'karaoke'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '86v#...';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'karaoke'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

$ mysql -ukaraoke -h localhost -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

...

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| karaoke            |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> use karaoke;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

I've updated my .env file with the db credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=karaoke
DB_USERNAME=karaoke
DB_PASSWORD=86v#...
```

However, when I try to run my migrations, I get the following error:

```
$ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'karaoke'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = karaoke and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕ 

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

What's gone wrong? I can login as karaoke user from the command line, but Laravel is having issues.

==

```
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 8.17.0

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

$ php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: have you tried `php artisan optimize:clear` ?

Comment: Tried it now, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Your password contains a `#` char, which might be misinterpreted as a comment in `.env`. Try using quotes: `DB_PASSWORD="86v#..."`

Comment: Ah, well spotted. Yeh that was the issue.